# Parse JSON to Name Value Collection in c#

Tags: c#, json, namevaluecollection

i have **JSON** Collection as Follows

```
[{"name":"SearchText","value":"smith"}]
```

This **Collection** value i have to change as Name Value **Collection**

```
Like {"SearchText","smith"}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question, it isn't very clear.